# SELECT * FROM dynamically retrieved table name

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery

Example: Below query returns **book** (primary table)

```
SELECT
    REFERENCED_TABLE_NAME
FROM
    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE
WHERE
    REFERENCED_TABLE_SCHEMA = 'mydatabase'
    AND TABLE_NAME = 'bookpage'
    AND COLUMN_NAME = 'bookid'
GROUP BY
    REFERENCED_TABLE_NAME
```

Now, I need to select some data from **book** table dynamically.
I just thought this logic would work but it did not

```
SELECT
    bookname
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            REFERENCED_TABLE_NAME
        FROM
            INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE
        WHERE
            REFERENCED_TABLE_SCHEMA = 'mydatabase'
            AND TABLE_NAME = 'bookpage'
            AND COLUMN_NAME = 'bookid'
        GROUP BY
            REFERENCED_TABLE_NAME
    )
```

What's the correct way?

Comment: 'What's the correct way?' - dynamic sql.https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-prepared-statements.html

Comment: You can't use  the result of a query as object name in sql.  if you really need  this you must use dynamic sql  ..  sql code sting concatenated  ad your string result

Comment: Please [edit] your title to something that summarizes your question. [ask]

Answer (score 1):

In SQL, all table names must be fixed and explicit at the time the query is prepared. There's no way to dynamically change the table name based on data read in the same query execution.

The most straightforward solution for you is to run two separate queries. One to get the name of the table you want to query, then use that result as you format the second query.